# Run an External Display Before Windows Boots on Laptop?

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, bios, external-display

The hinge on my laptop is broken, and I’ve been using an external display as the primary monitor, with an external keyboard and mouse. The laptop display still works, except I can only (force) open the lid a few inches. This is OK if I use Windows, as the external display turns on automatically while the OS boots. However, I would like to be able to use the external display before and OS boots, for reasons like going into BIOS or choosing boot options (I am planning to install Linux).

The laptop is an HP Envy, Dell external display, Nvidia video card. I use an HDMI cable for the monitor connection.

All the tricks I know involve being logged on to Windows (setting the closed lid power options, setting the external monitor as the primary display). Also, I believe there is a way to uninstall the internal display using Device Manager, but I would like to avoid that as I’m not completely sure how that works...

Is there any way of using the external display as a primary, while not completely disabling the internal display?

Thank you.

Comment: How about getting it to display the same thing on both?  That is what normally happens when I plug in an external monitor.

Comment: With the lid closed the video output goes only to the external monitor (the laptop display turns off). But this works only when you're logged on an OS anyway.

Comment: There are 3 settings: laptop only, monitor only or both.  Could you set it to both using F4.

Comment: On the Windows version I have (Windows 10 Home x64) those options don't exist. There is only Duplicate/Extend Display, or Show on Display 1 Only, Show on Display 2 Only. I have it set on Duplicate Displays (or Both, as you also suggested), but as soon as I log out of Windows, the external monitor no longer displays anything.

Comment: @cup the desktop setting is accessed via Windows+P, not F4. It may be available in the function key row but the position depends on the manufacturer. It's also **not** any function keys like F4 but Fn+Fx (or without Fn if you set the Function keys to be secondary)

Comment: F4 for Fn+F4 is the recommended method for HP laptops.  If it doesn't work on VGA, try the HDMI output.  Have a look at https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c03518165.  This works on my HP Envy regardless of OS.  This is HP's standard way of diagnosing whether the laptop display is faulty.

Comment: I haven't had much luck using F4, but Win+P works. Regardless, as I mentioned, the projection settings don't seem to hold w/o an OS running. For example, the HP logo never shows on my external display after a restart. I can't use BIOS, nor can I see boot options if I press F10. The first images I get are of Windows loading. I guess I may just need to use the laptop as is, until I buy a new one.